# why is `position:relative` functioning like `z-index`?

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I am relatively very new to HTML and CSS and have the following difficulty I made a small input box and I am trying to add a few CSS transforms and create a small animation on the input box. Code below:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}

.akira-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}

.akira-label {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #696a6e;
  color: #cc6055;
  cursor: text;
}

.akira-label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.50, 1);
  transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.50, 1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.label-content {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.6em 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<span class="input">
  <input type="text" id="akira" class="akira-input">
  <label for="akira" class="akira-label">
    <span class="label-content">Akira</span>
  </label>
</span>
```

My difficulty is, if I apply `position:relative` to `<span class="label-content">Akira</span>`, it shows, if I remove `position:relative` , that element disappears from view.

My question is why is `position:relative` functioning like `z-index`?

Can somebody elaborate ??

**EDIT** :: refering to Justinas answer , i have the folloing question ,

> Does applying position:relative places an element
>   higher in the stack , even without applying z-index ??

Comment: `position` and `z-index` are totally different. Also, I fail to replicate your problem. First of all you should not add `box-sizing` to every single element on the page. Then, try to find out where the problem comes from.

Comment: @Psioniax to replicate my problem , go to the styles of `.label-content` and take off `position: relative;` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` is only working for non-static elements, so when you remove `position: relative` than element becomes statically positioned and moves below higher index elements (*disappears from view*). When you add `position: relative` to element, than `z-index` will take effect and so element appears in your view.

Also `position` and `z-index` is two different properties
`position` - how element is positioned according to other elements on page. **Default to *static***
`z-index` - how *high* element is in z-axis (`z-index: 2` - is behind element with `z-index: 10`). **Default to *5***

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#static {
  position: static;
  z-index: 999;
  
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 3px;
}
#top-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  
  
  left: 8px;
  top: 45px;
  width: 330px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 3px;
}
#relative {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
  
  
  background-color: #88a;
  width: 330px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 3px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 8px;
}
#top-2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  
  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #dda;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div id="static">
    I'm static, so behind #top-1, but have z-index higher than #top-1... Means z-index has no effect.
    <br/>Text that is not visible, because behind #top-1 element
  </div>
  <div id='top-1'>
    I'm above #static, because i have non-static position, so my z-index has effect.
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div id="relative">
    I'm relative and above #top-2, because my z-index higher than #top-2... Means z-index has taken effect.
  </div>
  <div id='top-2'>
    I'm below #relative, because i have lover z-index.
    <br/>Text that is not visible, because behind #top-1 element
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you saying that applying `position:relative` places an element higher in the stack , even without applying z-index ??

Comment: No. Setting the position to something other than static merely provides the  ability for z-index to be leveraged, similar to that of `left` or `right` properties.

Comment: @Justinas , i am still confused :((((((

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Think of the word `static`, meaning `doesn't change`. Removing that allows certain transformations to occur.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Check out example.

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works on positioned elements so position:absolute, position:relative or position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

It does not behave like a `z-index`, because `z-index` specifies an ordering rule, but not the way how the element is displayed.

`position: relative;` says to go to the relative mode where it can compete the absolutely positioned elements.

Your problem here is that `:before` pseudo-element is a hierarchical sibling of `span`, and it takes the whole available parent width. So it fully covers a static `span` element.

When you make it relative, it becomes shown because when `z-index` is not specified for both non-static elements they are shown in the same order like they are placed in HTML (so element which is defined in HTML later is always on top).

Your structure is:

label

- :before
- span

so the span becomes visible.